# User does not have permission to perform this action

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a Website and it works fine locally (when I run it using MS Visual Studio 2010), but When I uploaded it on the Web, it gives me this [error message](http://bit.ly/g3aIUf)!

So, please what should I do to fix this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: What connection string you're using?

Comment: Show us how you are connecting. Is directory browsing enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the authentication information in your connection string.  Whatever user is trying to access the database, make sure they have permission.

Posting the connection string stored in ATRProDBConnStr might give more insight as well.

Answer (score 0):

> So, please what should I do to fix this problem?

You should check the permissions between the web application and the SQL server.

- Is the connection string correct (providing the correct user credentials for the application)?
- Does the production database have grant the same permissions to the application's database user as the local database?
- If the application doesn't use credentials, does the database grant the same permissions to the server's web application user as it does the local application user?

The error is basically SQL server telling you that your application isn't allowed to perform an action on the database.  The application works fine (except for the lack of error handling which generated this page), it just needs permissions on the SQL server.

Comment: Here is the connection string I'm using:

    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ATRProDBConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AIRProDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>